# mysql between multiple servers

Tags: mysql, server

If I have mysql installed on two servers, how would I enable a query to be executed on one or the other as follows:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM server1.mydb.names a LEFT JOIN server2.mydb.appointments b ON a.id=b.names_id
```

If mysql can't do that is there a transparent application which would translate that query into a behind-the-scene sequence like this:

```
/* on server1 */
[import server2.mydb.appointments(fields, needed) to
    server1.mydb.`__temporary__appointments`]
use mydb;
select a.*, b.* FROM mydb.names a 
    LEFT JOIN mydb.`__temporary__appointments` b ON a.id=b.name_id
```

Are there any applications out there that do this? Thanks

**EDIT**

@DaveMac was so kind as to point out Federated tables in mysql (see below).  It appears currently you cannot make the connection to an MSSQL server, but you could use ODBD to connect to mysql from MSSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at federated tables.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html